# MobileAds.initialize crashing App on startup

Tags: android, firebase, admob, chromium

I am extending the Application class & is initializing the admob as below:

```
    public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.admob_app_id));
    }
}
```

But the MobileAds.initialize method is crashing in my moto e2(API 23), whereas it is workng normal in my op3t (API 26). Below is the stack race of the crash:

```
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:11020
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 11020
D/DynamitePackage: Instantiated singleton DynamitePackage.
D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraMobileAdsSettingManagerCreatorImpl
V/ConnectivityManager: isActiveNetworkMetered() returns:false
I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 71.0.3578.99 (code 357809900)
I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 2 ms (timestamps 315-317)
I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(36)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "71.0.3578.99", actual native library version number "71.0.3578.99"
I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328] No pending exception expected: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: projekt.substratum
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at android.content.pm.PackageInfo android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(java.lang.String, int) (ApplicationPackageManager.java:137)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void org.chromium.base.BuildInfo.<init>() (PG:36)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void BT.<clinit>() (PG:2)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at java.lang.String[] org.chromium.base.BuildInfo.getAll() (PG:1)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void org.chromium.content.browser.BrowserStartupControllerImpl.nativeSetCommandLineFlags(boolean) (PG:-2)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void org.chromium.content.browser.BrowserStartupControllerImpl.b(boolean) (PG:55)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void FO.run() (PG:11)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void org.chromium.content.browser.BrowserStartupControllerImpl.a(boolean) (PG:24)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void yh.run() ((null):43)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void org.chromium.base.ThreadUtils.a(java.lang.Runnable) (PG:10)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void jP.b() (PG:112)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void jP.b(boolean) (PG:184)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void jP.a(boolean) (PG:165)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.a(boolean) (PG:243)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(java.util.Map, boolean) (PG:44)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:606)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:542)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:525)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:512)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context) (WebView.java:502)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.v.<init>(com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.au, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.av, java.lang.String, boolean, na, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.csi.l, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.bo, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.v, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.clearcut.a) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):1)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.q.call() ((null):4)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.bq.a(java.util.concurrent.Callable) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):19)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.i com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.o.a(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.av, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, na, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.csi.l, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.bo, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.v, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.clearcut.a) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):7)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.p.<init>(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p, na) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):5)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.y.run() ((null):17)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ad.execute(java.lang.Runnable) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):4)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.ap com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.x.a(na) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):13)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.al com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.x.a() (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):23)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.x com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.b.b(java.lang.Object) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):7)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ac.a(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p, boolean, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.state.e, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Runnable) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):27)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ac.a(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p, java.lang.String, java.lang.Runnable) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):3)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ay.a(java.lang.String, xk) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):50)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at boolean com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.be.dispatchTransaction(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):36)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at boolean of.onTransact(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):11)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at boolean android.os.Binder.transact(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) (Binder.java:387)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzew.zza(int, android.os.Parcel) ((null):20)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzye.zza(java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper) ((null):26)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzc.zza(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzf) ((null):26)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds$Settings) ((null):5)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) ((null):1)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void com.akl.alldrive.whatsapp.app.MyApplication.onCreate() (MyApplication.java:16)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(android.app.Application) (Instrumentation.java:1036)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:4728)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1415)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:148)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:5443)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:728)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:618)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1328] 
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399] Runtime aborting...
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399] Aborting thread:
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x74895f98 self=0xb73f6c60
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | sysTid=22940 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6fb0b34
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | state=R schedstat=( 1611581094 93694123 875 ) utm=143 stm=18 core=1 HZ=100
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | stack=0xbe61b000-0xbe61d000 stackSize=8MB
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #00 pc 0035c715  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+116)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #01 pc 0033d80f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+138)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #02 pc 00321915  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState10DumpThreadERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPNS_6ThreadE+20)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #03 pc 00321be3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+622)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #04 pc 000f3d4d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+2212)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #05 pc 0033c7fd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread24AssertNoPendingExceptionEv.part.170+360)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #06 pc 00133b73  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE+26)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #07 pc 001368f9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11ResolveTypeERKNS_7DexFileEtNS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS4_INS5_11ClassLoaderEEE+128)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #08 pc 001385f7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker13ResolveMethodERKNS_7DexFileEjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS4_INS5_11ClassLoaderEEEPNS_9ArtMethodENS_10InvokeTypeE+106)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #09 pc 003e5061  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker13ResolveMethodEPNS_6ThreadEjPNS_9ArtMethodENS_10InvokeTypeE.part.125+64)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #10 pc 003e8d09  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickResolutionTrampoline+2612)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #11 pc 000ea903  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_resolution_trampoline+34)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #12 pc 000dd135  /data/app/com.google.android.webview-1/oat/arm/base.odex (Java_org_chromium_base_BuildInfo__0003cinit_0003e__+664)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at org.chromium.base.BuildInfo.<init>(PG:44)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at BT.<clinit>(PG:2)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at org.chromium.base.BuildInfo.getAll(PG:1)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at org.chromium.content.browser.BrowserStartupControllerImpl.nativeSetCommandLineFlags(Native method)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at org.chromium.content.browser.BrowserStartupControllerImpl.b(PG:55)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at FO.run(PG:11)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at org.chromium.content.browser.BrowserStartupControllerImpl.a(PG:24)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at yh.run(unavailable:43)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at org.chromium.base.ThreadUtils.a(PG:10)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at jP.b(PG:112)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at jP.b(PG:184)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at jP.a(PG:165)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   - locked <0x09ac162e> (a java.lang.Object)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.a(PG:243)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(PG:44)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:606)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:542)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:525)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:512)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:502)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.v.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):1)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.q.call(unavailable:4)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.bq.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):19)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):7)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.p.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):5)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.y.run(unavailable:17)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ad.execute(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):4)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.x.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):13)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.x.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):23)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   - locked <0x0bc0bbe1> (a java.lang.Object)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.b.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):7)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ac.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):27)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ac.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):3)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ay.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):50)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.be.dispatchTransaction(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):36)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at of.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):11)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzew.zza(unavailable:20)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzye.zza(unavailable:26)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzc.zza(unavailable:26)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   - locked <0x0b54bd06> (a java.lang.Object)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(unavailable:5)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(unavailable:1)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.akl.alldrive.whatsapp.app.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:16)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1036)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4728)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java:-1)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1415)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399] Pending exception android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: projekt.substratum
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at android.content.pm.PackageInfo android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(java.lang.String, int) (ApplicationPackageManager.java:137)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void org.chromium.base.BuildInfo.<init>() (PG:36)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void BT.<clinit>() (PG:2)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at java.lang.String[] org.chromium.base.BuildInfo.getAll() (PG:1)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void org.chromium.content.browser.BrowserStartupControllerImpl.nativeSetCommandLineFlags(boolean) (PG:-2)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void org.chromium.content.browser.BrowserStartupControllerImpl.b(boolean) (PG:55)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void FO.run() (PG:11)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void org.chromium.content.browser.BrowserStartupControllerImpl.a(boolean) (PG:24)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void yh.run() ((null):43)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void org.chromium.base.ThreadUtils.a(java.lang.Runnable) (PG:10)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void jP.b() (PG:112)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void jP.b(boolean) (PG:184)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void jP.a(boolean) (PG:165)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.a(boolean) (PG:243)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(java.util.Map, boolean) (PG:44)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:606)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:542)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:525)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:512)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context) (WebView.java:502)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.v.<init>(com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.au, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.av, java.lang.String, boolean, na, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.csi.l, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.bo, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.v, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.clearcut.a) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):1)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.q.call() ((null):4)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.bq.a(java.util.concurrent.Callable) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):19)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.i com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.o.a(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.av, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, na, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.csi.l, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.bo, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.v, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.clearcut.a) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):7)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.p.<init>(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p, na) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):5)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.y.run() ((null):17)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ad.execute(java.lang.Runnable) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):4)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.ap com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.x.a(na) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):13)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.al com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.x.a() (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):23)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.x com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.b.b(java.lang.Object) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):7)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ac.a(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p, boolean, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.state.e, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Runnable) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):27)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ac.a(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p, java.lang.String, java.lang.Runnable) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):3)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ay.a(java.lang.String, xk) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):50)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at boolean com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.be.dispatchTransaction(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):36)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at boolean of.onTransact(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799045@14.7.99 (040304-223214910):11)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at boolean android.os.Binder.transact(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) (Binder.java:387)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzew.zza(int, android.os.Parcel) ((null):20)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzye.zza(java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper) ((null):26)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzc.zza(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzf) ((null):26)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds$Settings) ((null):5)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) ((null):1)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void com.akl.alldrive.app.MyApplication.onCreate() (MyApplication.java:16)
```

The gradle details are as follows:

```
    compileSdkVersion 28

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.akl.alldrive"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 24
            versionName "3.3.2"
...
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    //Firebase dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.2'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.4'

    //Android SDK
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'

    //3rd Party Dependencies
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.apl-devs:appintro:v4.2.3'
    implementation 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.5'

    implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-beta02"
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
}
```

Please help me how to fix this problem.

Comment: We have initialized this on other thread as well

Answer (score 1):

```java
if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (this)) {
    MobileAds.initialize (this, appid);
}

public boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (Context context) {
    GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance ();
    int resultCode = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (context);
    return resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
}
```